# Any way to make a radial gradient into an oval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gradient

So at the moment i'm working on a small project that renders an isometric tile space using diamonds that are at a height : width ratio of 1:2.

I plan on making a "shield" effect above them by basically putting more and more blue closer to the edges with the inner circle being transparent to give the illusion of a semi-transparent sphere being above it.

To do this i am using radial gradient.

Currently my canvas when rendered looks like this:

[image]

And my code looks like this:

```
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(450, tileheight * 5 / 2, 100, 450, tileheight * 5 / 2, 200);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0, 0, 55, 0.5)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(10, 10, 55, 0.8)");
drawdiamond(gradient, 450, 0, tilewidth * 5, tileheight * 5);
```

Where drawdiamond is a function that draws the tiles, this function will draw a diamond the size of the map with the gradient specified by the variable "gradient".

And tilewidth and tileheight are the width and height at the longest parts of each tile, they are 100 and 50 respectively.

If you look at the image, there is a problem, since i'm drawing my tiles to be wider than they are taller, i need to draw an oval where the height is half the radius of the width in order for the effect to be convincing.

There is ctx.setPattern where i can make an image that has the gradient i want, but if i want to make the map bigger during run time, i would need to create multiple images for each size, which is not ideal.

Is there a way to transform the image gradient so it draws an oval instead of a circle?

(Sorry if this has already been posted).

Comment: This is a good question I've never thought about before. [This article](http://rectangleworld.com/blog/archives/169) suggests you'd have to change the transform scale to achieve it

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the  `gradientUnits` and `gradientTransform` attributes to squeeze the radiant?

Comment: @neuhaus this question is about canvas2d, not svg

Answer (score 2):

Matt posted an article that suggested making a shape that is larger than it should be height wise, they use ctx.transform to set the height scaling to 0.5, which will scale the gradient with it as it's part of what's drawn.

I played around with it and came up with this, thanks for the help!

```
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(450, tilewidth * mapsize / 2, 100, 450, tilewidth * mapsize / 2, 200);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(0, 0, 55, 0.5)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(10, 10, 55, 0.8)");
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0);
drawdiamond(gradient, 450, 0, tilewidth * mapsize, tilewidth * mapsize);
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

[image]

This function draws the diamond with the shield effect at double it's intended height, then scales it down when it is drawn, thus causing a scaled gradient.

Map size is the maps length in tiles on both length and height sides.

This will work for any size map.